# ng repeat list not getting updated when menu and content is in different template (Ionic Framework)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on one ionic framework project.

Where am stuck of list not getting updated. Once menu item is clicked the list should be updated accordingly.

As both things are in different controller I don't have any idea how I can do scope.apply

Below is mine code.

Menu.html

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-assertive">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear button-icon ion-ios-arrow-back">
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="mainContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
      <h1 class="title">Services</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>   


   <div class="list" ng-controller="serviceCtrl as vm">


 <a menu-close class="item item-icon-right item-dark" ng-repeat="services in vm.menu" ng-click="vm.setService(services.id)">


  {{services.name}}

<i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right ion-accessory"></i>
</a>
</div>
      <!-- </ion-content> -->
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Menu services

```
angular.module('starter').controller('serviceCtrl', ['$state','serviceFactory','$scope','$rootScope', serviceCtrl]);

        function serviceCtrl($state, serviceFactory,$scope,$rootScope) {
            var vm = this;

            var menu = serviceFactory.getService();
            vm.menu = menu;

        /*  var data = serviceFactory.getService();
            vm.menu = data.menu;*/


            vm.setService = function(menuId){
                //$scope.$apply(function() {
                //alert('a');
                serviceFactory.setService(menuId);
                //$scope.subServiceId = menuId;
                $state.go('app.sub');
setTimeout(function(){ 
                alert('asdf')
            $scope.$apply()
            }, 300);
                //});
            };


    };
```

LIst page that needs to be updated

```
<ion-view view-title="{{vm.menu[vm.subServiceId-1]['name']}}" ng-controller="subServiceCtrl as vm">
  <ion-content>
<div class="list">

 <a class="item item-icon-right" ng-repeat="services in lists" ng-click="vm.setSubService(services.sname)">
    {{services.sname}}
<i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right ion-accessory"></i>
</a>
</div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And list controller

```
angular.module('starter').controller('subServiceCtrl',['$state','serviceFactory','$scope','$rootScope',subServiceCtrl]);

function subServiceCtrl($state,serviceFactory,$scope,$rootScope) {

var vm = this;

//get the sub services

            var menu = serviceFactory.getService();
    $scope.menua = menu;
        var subServiceIda = serviceFactory.actSercice();
    vm.subServiceId = serviceFactory.getSelected();
        $rootScope.lists = menu[subServiceIda-1].subItems;

    alert('as check');
    console.log(vm.subServiceId);
    alert("First level menu id is "+vm.subServiceId);
    vm.menuId = serviceFactory.setFirstId();
    //to get the selected sub item. second call to  setService()
//$scope.$apply();
if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()

    vm.setSubService = function(subname) {
    serviceFactory.setService(subname);
    $state.go('app.next');
    //$scope.$apply();
    };

};
```

Comment: you have to define correct ng-repeat value

Comment: ng-repeat="services in lists"

you have to user ng-repeat="serives in vm.list"

Comment: hey @Ahmer mine code is working fine. it atleast loads one time. but when I tried with your one it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I ownself solved it.

Just added

```
cache: false,
```

in RouterProvider.